# Matlab sending error when BaseTable is used with cell array in a report

Tags: matlab

I am trying to put a cell array in my report however I keep getting errors when I try to close the report.
I suppose it comes from the fact that there are numbers and strings in my cell array because for singular type arrays I don't have any problem. (However I tried to sweep my array with num2str and i get the same error...)

I am doing this:

```
SectionPASS = Section;
SectionPASS.Title = 'PASS example';
[PASSrow,~] = find(cellfun(@(x)isequal(x,'PASS'),raw));    
temp = (raw(PASSrow(1),:));
tablePASS = BaseTable(temp);
add(SectionPASS, tablePASS);
add(ChapterTests, SectionPASS);
add(rpt, ChapterTests);
close(rpt)
rptview(rpt)
```

This gives me a very long java error that ends with

```
Error in rptgen.utils.FOPProxy.foToPDF (line 84)
            foToPDFImpl(h, foPath, pdfPath, locale, extraFonts, cleanupFonts);

Error in mlreportgen.report.ReportBase/close

Error in Master_Report (line 95)
close(rpt)
```

I think the problem comes from BaseTable because if I use cell2table on temp it finally works but it also gives me headers that I don't want...

---

```
temp =

  2×20 cell array

{'lvl'}    {'Mains, …'}    {'Expected Mains …'}    {'Protection …'}    {'Mains m…'}    {'Calculated…'}    {'Calculated…'} {'Mains m…'}    {'Final …'}    {'Final…'}    {'Test Case Summary'}    {'No Transition t…'}    {'Transition …'}    {'Transition …'} {'Trace'}    {'Plot File'  }    {'Matlab'  }    {'JPEG Fig' }    {'Pass?Fail'}    {' '}
{[ 2.6300]}    {[         295.6000]}    {[         295.7509]}    {' pfc_ovp_snsboost'}    {[         295.6130]}    {[         416.6599]}    {[           2.6288]} {[         295.4511]}    {[         416.4310]}    {[           2.6273]}    {'ActiveX VT_ERRO…'}    {[                0]}    {'PASS'             }    {[           2.6280]} {'Matlab FIG\O_…'}    {'JPG Plots\O_l…'}    {'Matlab FIG\OVP_…'}    {'JPG Plots\OVP_l…'}    {'PASS'           }    {' '}
```

---

Do you know what I am supposed to do to make this work because I really don't understand? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `SectionPASS`? Do you get the error in `tablePASS = BaseTable(temp);` or after? I am not getting an error in the line `tablePASS = BaseTable(temp);`, but can't continue execution because `SectionPASS` is missing.

Comment: @Rotem sorry for not adding that. SectionPASS is a section object. ChapterPASS a chapter object and rpt the Report object

Comment: @Rotem I get the error at the end when i try to close the report `close(rpt)`. But I think the error comes from `BaseTable` or somewhere close because if I transform my cell array into a table everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `FormalTable` to solve my problem. I still don't really know why BaseTable gave an error though.